# Searching in Redis evaluating Lua script

Tags: lua, redis

I'm trying to search for field value in hash using Lua script and I'm doing something wrong :)
I have key "articles" which is zset holding article IDs and keys article:n where "n" is the article number.
The following script:

```
local ids = redis.call("zrange", 'articles', '0', '-1')
local ret = {}
for k, id in pairs(ids) do
    local row = redis.call("hgetall", "article:"..id)
    ret[k] = row
end
return ret
```

returns this:

```
1)  1) "slug"
    2) "first-title"
    3) "title"
    4) "first title"
2)  1) "slug"
    2) "second-title"
    3) "title"
    4) "second title"
```

Than I'm trying to include condition to return only keys containing string "second" in title but it returns nothing.

```
local ids = redis.call("zrange", 'articles', '0', '-1')
local ret = {}
for k, id in pairs(ids) do
    local row = redis.call("hgetall", "article:"..id)
    if (string.find(row[4], "second")) then
        ret[k] = row
    end
end
return ret
```

Please could you help me?

Comment: Regardless the issue with the condition, you should note that all key names that are used in the script should be passed using the `KEYS` argument table - dynamically accessing keys (e.g. based on the contents of a Sorted Set range) is not ensured to work in a clustered environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The table you returned from lua, must be an array whose index staring from `1`.**

However, In your example, only the second article matches the condition, and its index is `2`. So you are, in fact, setting the table as: `ret[2] = row`. Since the returned table is NOT an array whose index starting from `1`, Redis takes it as an empty array, and you get nothing.

**Solution:**

```
local ids = redis.call("zrange", 'articles', '0', '-1')
local ret = {}
local idx = 1;  -- index starting from 1
for k, id in pairs(ids) do
    local row = redis.call("hgetall", "article:"..id)
    if (string.find(row[4], "second")) then
        ret[idx] = row   -- set table
        idx = idx + 1    -- incr index by 1
    end
end
return ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @for_stack, finally I have some solution for simple searching on server side, which as I assume will work much better than matching on client side because only related data will be transferred :)

Comment: @ivan73 Just for reminding: you should be very careful with too complicated lua scripts. Since it runs atomically, and Redis is single-threaded, it blocks the Redis process. Especially, if the script is too complicated (do too much work), it blocks Redis for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition

`if (string.find(row[4], "second") ~= nil) then`

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nikita, I tried that, but it doesn't work.